# find all requests in which user is participant in the service desk

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

In JIRA, how to get the all issues which user is participant?
I can get the results for assignee and reporter.

I am using following query to get the issues when the user is reporter.

> reporter = user AND updated > -10d

I need to display the issues only the user is participant not the reporter or assignee. How to achieve this in the search API?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use the Jira's search API, given that you're looking for issues that the user is a participant of, try adding this in your JQL `"Request participants" in (currentUser())`.

Since you're concerned with Jira Service Desk (JSD), you might want to try the following JSD specific REST APIs depending on which deployment you're working with:

- Server: [Get my customer requests](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/3.6.2/#servicedeskapi/request-getMyCustomerRequests) then pass *requestOwnership* query parameter with the value of *PARTICIPATED_REQUESTS*.
- Cloud: [Get customer requests](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/#api-request-get) then pass *requestOwnership* query parameter with the value of *PARTICIPATED_REQUESTS*.

EDIT: (added code snippet)

```
app.get('/getMyRequests', addon.checkValidToken(), function(req, res) {
var httpClient = addon.httpClient(req).asUserByAccountId("myAccountId");

httpClient.get({
    url: '/rest/servicedeskapi/request',
    headers: {
        'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
},
function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('successful:', body);
});});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  we are using the Cloud, when using the basic authentication the `/rest/servicedeskapi/request` is working fine, i can able to see the issues, but when using JWT authentication,it was not working since we are using the add-on to connect the jira API.

Comment: As long as you're using the READ scope, accessing it via add-on should be fine. Are you using the ACE framework for your connect app? Have you tried impersonating a user prior to calling the REST API?

Comment: When i use JQL i am getting the following response ```{"errorMessages":["Field 'participants' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."],"warningMessages":[]}```

Comment: Yes i tried, all other API's are working fine except this request using the add-on. Is it because of GET request? The search API was working since it is POST request. I am sending the parameters as json inside the body.

Comment: GET should work. I added a working code snippet that I just tested a few minutes ago. Please include "ACT_AS_USER" in the scope. I used ACE for this one

Comment: I already added `ACT_AS_USER` in the scope when add-on creation. ACE for node.js i believe, I am using rails. i will check based on your code snippet. Thanks for the help